# Traceback Error while installing any module in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am unable to install any module in python3. I keep on getting traceback errors.I am unable to resolve the problem .
[Error while installing Pygame-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT2nJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read timeouts generally occur when you have an unstable/weak internet connection, so what's probably happening is your connection is dropping during installation. Check your connection, retry pip and it should work if your connection is strong, it should work!